# App Inventor: Open links in new window from a webview?

Tags: android, app-inventor

How can I make sure that all links in the webview component in an app-inventor program always opens as a new window? ie, using "full browser".

I checked the *FollowLinks* option but that just opens the links within the webview only.
Unchecking that option disables all links inside webview.

Also, the hyperlink displayed inside the webview has the `target="_blank"` attribute set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately this is not possible with the webview in App Inventor, however you could use the activity starter to start a browser instead
Taifun

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by extending the [`WebViewClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) and overloading the [`shouldOverrideUrlLoading`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) method. This method gets called whenever you click a link within the webview.

In your overload method you will generate an intent to open the browser and start an activity with this intent. Finally you use the [`setWebViewClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setWebViewClient%28android.webkit.WebViewClient%29) method on your webview and pass your extended `WebViewClient` as a parameter.

I have some example code within a project on [github](https://github.com/DokuWikiMobile/dokuwikimobile/blob/alpha/src/org/dokuwikimobile/ui/view/DokuwikiWebView.java#L115). In line [115](https://github.com/DokuWikiMobile/dokuwikimobile/blob/alpha/src/org/dokuwikimobile/ui/view/DokuwikiWebView.java#L115) the `WebViewClient` is set. In this example only special links will be loaded in external browser. The intent for that is generated in line [130](https://github.com/DokuWikiMobile/dokuwikimobile/blob/alpha/src/org/dokuwikimobile/ui/view/DokuwikiWebView.java#L130).

Comment: these might be some good answers, but not to that question, which is about App Inventor http://www.appinventor.mit.edu/